# Read serial input from RS232 to USB converter

Tags: usb, conversion, rs232, barcode-scanner

I want to connect a barcode scanner to my PC and read its output from a selfmade program. I know that there are basically two methods of obtaining output from a barcode scanner:

1. As *Keyboard Wedge* - which means that the scanner is simulating
   keyboard presses
2. *Serial Communication* with RS232 - which is what I want to use.

Unfortunately I cannot find a scanner that supports serial communication **and** is connected with USB.

So my question is: Can I take a RS232 to USB converter and then read the output of the scanner as if it were connected to a RS232 port? Is any additional software (like drivers) required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work. Some networking devices use this all the time. Since modern PCs no longer have RS232, an adapted must be used to access older devices.

The adapter comes usually with a driver and even additional software.

Practically, the adapter + driver allow the emulation of an RS232 that will allow you to be able to access the device using the fake/emulated RS232 interface just like accessing it with a real physical direct RS232 connection.

Comment: Thank you! I have another small question maybe you also know the anser. If the device is only specified as *Keyboard-Wedge*, will it only work as "virtual keyboard" or can I still read the output of the device from a program?

Comment: It should be fine to read, because a device using a keyboard wedge can't tell the difference between data that is entered by a scanning device, or data that is entered by keyboard typing.